# Disabling a submit button using JQuery if a value has not been selected from a specific dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to disable a submit button if a value from a specific dropdown has not been selected.  The code for the dropdown and button looks like this:

```
    <li>
    <select name="names" id="names">
    <option value="">Constituency</option>
    <!-- populates the drop down with names -->
    <?php foreach ($cons as $constituency): ?>
    <option value="<?php htmlout($constituency['ids']); ?>">
    <?php htmlout($constituency['names']); ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if (isset($selectError)): ?>
    <p><?php htmlout($selectError); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </select>
    </li>

    <li><input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="button search" id="jsbutton" disabled="disabled"></li>
```

So the dropdown has an id of 'names' and the button has an id of 'jsbutton' and is set to 'disabled' .

I then try to target it with the following JQuery but the button remains disabled regardless:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('#names').val() = '')
    {
        $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    });
```

So what I am trying to do is:

- Check if value has been selected from dropdpwn.
- IF it hasn't then leave button disabled.
- ELSE a value has been selected from the dropdown and therefore the button should be enabled.

Any help on this is appreciated.

PHP TO POPULATE THE DROPDOWN:

```
          try
      {
        $cons_result = $pdo->query("SELECT id, name 
                               FROM constituency 
                               ORDER BY name");
      }
      catch (PDOException $e)
      {
        $error = 'Error fetching constituencies from database!' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
      }


      foreach ($cons_result as $rows)
      {
        $cons[] = array('ids' => $rows['id'], 'names' => $rows['name']);
      }

      include 'searchform.html.php';
    }
```

Comment: Added the PHP that populates the dropdown.

This is working fine, i.e. the dropdown gets populated with all of the constituencies from a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#names").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          if ($("#names option:selected").val()=='')
            {

                $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
            }
            else
            {

                $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<select id="names">
    <option value=0>Please Select</option>
    <?php ($cons as $constituency) {...} ?>
</select>
<input id="jsbutton" type="submit" disabled />
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#names').change(function(e) {
        if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") === 0)
        {
            $('#jsbutton').prop('disabled', true);  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#jsbutton').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/akuguy/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks Sheikh, this does the job.

Do you know the equivalent in JQuery though?  I know JQuery is a javascript library but I would like to know the pure JQuery solution.

Comment: This is the `jQuery` solution not pure `javacsript`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `change` event of the select box, so when the value changes, you check again if something is selected and then change your button!

**Also note the `==` in the `if` statement**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#names').change(function() {
        if ($('#names').val() == '')
        {
            $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
        }
        else
        {
            $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work.

The search button is permanently disabled regardless of whether a value is chosen from the drop down or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
<select name="names" id="names" onChange='editButton(this.value);'>
<option value="">Constituency</option>
<!-- populates the drop down with names -->
<?php foreach ($cons as $constituency): ?>
<option value="<?php htmlout($constituency['ids']); ?>">
<?php htmlout($constituency['names']); ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if (isset($selectError)): ?>
<p><?php htmlout($selectError); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</select>
</li>

<li><input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="button search" id="jsbutton" disabled="disabled"></li>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function editButton(value){
if (value == '')
    {
        $('#jsbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#jsbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
</script>
```

editButton function called every time you change a value in the dropdown. So it will disable the button if the value is null.

Comment: Same as above comment to previous answer. This doesn't work unortunately. The search button is permanently disabled regardless of whether a value is chosen from the drop down or not

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#names').val() =='' instead of $('#names').val() = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <li>
            <select name="names" id="names"> <!-- if it's not selected then disabled the submit button right? -->
            <option value="">Constituency</option>
            <!-- populates the drop down with names -->
            <?php foreach ($cons as $constituency): ?>
            <option value="<?php htmlout($constituency['ids']); ?>">
            <?php htmlout($constituency['names']); ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if (isset($selectError)): ?>
            <p><?php htmlout($selectError); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
            </li>

            <li><input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"></li>

    <!-- then below is what you need to modify, add "onchange" and disabled -->

        <li><input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="button search" id="jsbutton" onchange="submitDisOrUndisabled();" disabled></li>

    <!-- and add function below -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitDisOrUndisabled()
        {
            if($('#names').val() != 0) {
                $('#jsbutton').prop('disabled', false);
            }else{$('#jsbutton').prop('disabled', true);}

        }
 </script>   
    <!-- I've tried it and it works very well -->
```

Comment: You should explain what you're doing, what you changed, rather than just pasting a blob of html.

Comment: make sure to include the jquery.js before the function.